# How to get same Regex matches combined?

Tags: c#, regex

If I want to find all the text inside brackets in a string using a regex, I would have something like this:

```
string text = "[the] [quick] brown [fox] jumps over [the] lazy dog";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([^]]+)\]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    ... // Here is my problem!
}
```

I am not sure how to continue my code from here, if I just iterate through all matches, I will get `"the"`, `"quick"`, `"fox"` and `"the"`, I was expecting to get the two `the` grouped in the same `Match.Group`, just at different indexes.

What I *really* want is to get the two `"the"` grouped in such a way I can find **all occurrences of the same word and their indexes.**

I was hoping the API will give me something like this:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{   
    for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        StartIndexesList.Add(match.Groups[i].Index);
    }
}
```

Where each `match.Group` will hold a reference to the same occurrence in the text of some found token, so I expected this code will add all the `the` text index references to a list at once, but it doesn't, it just adds for each separate occurrence, not all at once.

**How can I achieve this without post processing all the tokens to see if there are repeated ones?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
string text = "[the] [quick] brown [fox] jumps over [the] lazy dog";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([^]]+)\]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);

foreach (IGrouping<string, Match> group in matches.Cast<Match>().GroupBy(_ => _.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);   // This will print '[the]'

    foreach (Match match in group)  // It will iterate through all matches of '[the]'
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I was expecting something from the `Regex` API itself but I guess there isn't one after all.